# Removing White Space in Char Array

Tags: java

I figured out why only half of my columns are printing out. The file that has all the characters have white space between them. The print method is also reading in the white space.

```
 Ex: a b c d
     e f g h
```

There are some String methods that trim and remove, but I cannot use that with a char. Does anyone know what I may be able to use to remove the white space?

```
public void print()
{
   for(int i = rows; i < board.length; i++)
   {
       for(int j = columns; j < board[0].length; j++)
       {
           System.out.print( board[i][j] );
       }
       System.out.println();
   }
}
```

}

Comment: What specific problems are you having? It'll help others help you :-)

Comment: The main problem I am having is that the board is printing out all of the rows, but it is only printing out half of the columns. I don't know why only half of the columns are printing out.

Answer (score 0):

I think this method is wrong

```
public void print()
{
   for(int i = rows; i < board.length; i++)
   {
       for(int j = columns; j < board[0].length; j++)
       {
           System.out.print( board[i][j] );
       }
       System.out.println();
   }
}
```

`for(int i = rows; i < board.length; i++)` looks suspicious, should the loop start from 0 instead?

Comment: That should be fine, it's a grid of one width and height so every board[i] will have the same width.

Comment: @MatthewC Does the board have to be a square? It seems row/col are coming from a file. We don't know if they are the same always.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the issue is in the outer loop. For sure you want to start looping with `i = 0`

Comment: @Takendarkk No it doesn't have to be a square, it could be a rectangle. But the point is each row is going to have the same width and each column will have the same height.

Comment: @MatthewC I see your meaning now. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I tried starting with i = 0, but the problem is still there. Only half of the columns are printing out.

Answer (score 0):

You used board[0] instead of board[i] in your print method.

```
for(int j = columns; j < board[i].length; j++)
   {
       System.out.print( board[i][j] );
   }
   System.out.println();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is your problem.
Your code in the for loops:

for(int i = rows; i...

Starts at row, and column. It should start at 0 and go to row and column like so:

for(int i = 0; i < rows...

The other posts that tell you the problem is you are going to board[0].length instead of board[i].length, cannot be correct because you are working with a grid that has one length and one height. That won't change from board[0].length to board[1].length, etc..

Comment: I don't know what you're doing but I took out the part in your constructor that opens a file and then does nothing with it. And it works fine.

Comment: Output: 10 5
Enter how many generations to compute: 7
Generation 1:
XXXYXYYYXX
XXYYYXXYYX
YXXYXYXXXX
YYXXYYXXXX
YYXXXXYXXX
Generation 2
XXXYXYYYXX
XXYYYXXYYX
YXXYXYXXXX
YYXXYYXXXX
YYXXXXYXXX
Generation 3
XXXYXYYYXX
XXYYYXXYYX
YXXYXYXXXX
YYXXYYXXXX
YYXXXXYXXX              Instead of doing whatever you were doing, I just read in rows and columns from the keyboard.

Comment: You REALLY need to look at the warning you have, they are over 10. It's extremely easy to fix. Half of them say, "This X wasn't used", or "This Y wasn't closed". Fix them. Then worry about why your code won't work when it doesn't have any errors. Right now you need to clean up or it will be 10000x more difficult to find the problem now. But, like I said, it works fine for me.

Comment: What do you mean by look at the warning? I am only in a beginning java class so I don't have much knowledge.

Comment: When you compile your program, it says "10 Warnings found", they are: .....  You should read them and try to fix them. Warning are like errors but less serious, although they should not be ignored.